# My codeigniter project only loads the home page, the navigation links won't wok

Tags: php, codeigniter

I made a codeigniter project locally. Then I upload it to my domain, but the only thing it loads is my home page and data from my database. The navigation doesn't work, even the pagination from my home page.

Everything works before I uploaded it. I don't see any php errors too.
"ERROR 404 - PAGE NOT FOUND"

What do you think is the problem?

**config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://thegamerx.net/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

**autoload.php**

```
$autoload['packages'] = array();
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','form_validation','pagination','session');
$autoload['helper'] = array('html','url','text','form','utility');
$autoload['config'] = array();
$autoload['language'] = array();
$autoload['model'] = array('blog_model');
```

Comment: update the `$config['base_url']` in config.php

Comment: $config['base_url'] = ''; that's my config. what shoud i update it to?

Comment: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://fullDomainNameHere/';`

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'http://thegamerx.net/';

still wont work.

Comment: update the question with .htaccess and routes.php

Comment: done with the update

Comment: Did you used `url helper` on links like `echo base_url();`??

Comment: Add `RewriteBase /` in your .htaccess in your project root.

Comment: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://thegamerx.net/'; $config['index_page'] = '';  $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';` These lines are from config.php and not from routes.php. Update this line `$config['index_page'] = '';` to `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` and update the question with routes.php

Comment: sorry about that. thanks for correcting. i was double checking my routes at that time. anyways i'll try your solution. edit is done for the question

Comment: What version of codeigniter are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display enable errors on server, than you will know what to do next

Comment: thanks. htaccess was the problem. it's working now

Answer (score 1):

Set your base URL in config.php file like

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://your_domain_name_here';
```

Comment: '$config['base_url'] = 'http://thegamerx.net/';  still error when navigating through the site.

Comment: Plz include http also

Comment: http is included there. it just wont show. dunno. i dont know how to use the code tag here

Comment: Do you use any .htaccess ??

Comment: for htacess and routes. i put them in the question. take a look for the update

Comment: add RewriteBase /your_domain_name/ in your .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Wait, your site works with the `www` prefix. You probably have your config with the `www` on it. Anyway, adding a redirect rule to redirect the blank domain might help.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thegamerx.net
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.thegamerx.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Be careful of 301 redirects though, they are permanent (browsers and search engines cache them). You might want to try with a 302 to make sure it works before going to 301.

Answer (score 0):

config.php (inside Config Folder)

```
# DEVELOPMENT SERVER
$config['base_url'] = 'http://thegamerx.net';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Put this .htaccess on your very root folder, same level as application folder, system folder, and index.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

If you have access to our server configuration (usually under /etc/apache2/sites-available/your-site-config-file.conf), try to set the following:

```
<Directory /your/site/root/folder/>
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```